# How can I move an image on a page and have it maintain position in real time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

Me and a group of friends are working on an experimental project for a show.

Objective: We want to have multiple objects ( such as imagery, text, gifs ) that exist on a page and can be moved around on that page with a draggable script and maintain position in real time. We plan on having a few people access the page at a time to move objects around on screen. So the idea is to create some kind of collaborate collage with multiple screens/devices.

I came across this 
[www.togetherjs.com/examples/drawing/](https://togetherjs.com/examples/drawing/)

So I want to take this idea of the drawing with others, but implement draggable imagery instead and I want the images to maintain position once moved.

What would I add to ensure that the images stay in the same spot, can be dragged in real time, and maintain the new position as well? 
I have already started something here http://jsfiddle.net/bj2ftf59/

```js
var dragobject = {
  z: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  offsetx: null,
  offsety: null,
  targetobj: null,
  dragapproved: 0,
  initialize: function() {
    document.onmousedown = this.drag
    document.onmouseup = function() {
      this.dragapproved = 0
    }
  },
  drag: function(e) {
    var evtobj = window.event ? window.event : e
    this.targetobj = window.event ? event.srcElement : e.target
    if (this.targetobj.className == "drag") {
      this.dragapproved = 1
      if (isNaN(parseInt(this.targetobj.style.left))) {
        this.targetobj.style.left = 0
      }
      if (isNaN(parseInt(this.targetobj.style.top))) {
        this.targetobj.style.top = 0
      }
      this.offsetx = parseInt(this.targetobj.style.left)
      this.offsety = parseInt(this.targetobj.style.top)
      this.x = evtobj.clientX
      this.y = evtobj.clientY
      if (evtobj.preventDefault)
        evtobj.preventDefault()
      document.onmousemove = dragobject.moveit
    }
  },
  moveit: function(e) {
    var evtobj = window.event ? window.event : e
    if (this.dragapproved == 1) {
      this.targetobj.style.left = this.offsetx + evtobj.clientX - this.x + "px"
      this.targetobj.style.top = this.offsety + evtobj.clientY - this.y + "px"
      return false
    }
  }
}

dragobject.initialize()
```

```css
.drag {
  position: relative;
  cursor: hand;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TogetherJS(this); return false;">Start TogetherJS</button>
<br>

<img src="http://www.giraffeworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/Beautiful_Masai_Giraffe_Posing_600.jpg" class="drag" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.giraffeworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/Beautiful_Masai_Giraffe_Posing_600.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.giraffeworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/Beautiful_Masai_Giraffe_Posing_600.jpg'"
alt="Giraffe Boy" title="Giraffe Boy" class="Glassware" max-width="20px" />



<script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are missing the most important piece of technology to make everything real-time. Node.js, or Websockets, if you're not into frameworks.

Comment: The problem you are solving requires a realtime server to monitor the position of an image and push those changes to all connected clients in realtime. I will prefer meteorJS for this project. Other challenges invloved in this project is how to manage different screen resolutions of client?

Comment: @Mohd Asim Suhail  Thank you for your input. I will look in all of these. Much appreciated.

Comment: @GiamPy Thank you for your input. I will look into all of these. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JqueryUI to accomplish this.

Simply create a Div with class "daggable-box"

```
<div class="draggable-box">
  something in here
</div>
```

Then in your JS file add the following.

```
 $(".draggable-box").draggable();
 $(".draggable-box").resizable();
```

Example: http://codepen.io/rmfranciacastillo/pen/wWoYao

Btw, the position that the object was dragged will NOT be saved but you may be able to save it since you can get the position of the object and save it in your database.

I'm only suggesting this since you have a tag of JQuery but I still consider this to be an overkill for a simple project.

Comment: I see, my mistake for tagging JQuery. Could you elaborate on what you mean when you say "I still consider this to be an overkill for a simple project." ? Are you saying that your solution + saving position in database would be overkill?

Comment: I mean that adding a huge library like Jquery for just dragging objects would be an overkill since JQuery is made to handle multiple cases. It's the equivalent of buying a Boeing 747 just to get free peanuts. It's better to find a more dedicated library or make one yourself. The saving position can be accomplished with a framework and a DB. But that goes beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: I understand. Thank you, I sincerely appreciate your time. Some of the other comments above recommended NodeJS and MeteorJS so I am looking into those. If you don't mind, do you recognize any of these / would you recommend them?

Comment: NodeJs is an event-driven server-side framework that might be able to handle the dragging event. But don't know what extensions might be able to handle them. Unfortunately, I don't know much about MeteorJS.

Comment: Great! Thanks again.